# Trouble with replacement while implementing composite pattern

Tags: java

I am working on composite pattern . I have a program  that accepts the data from the csv file and have to print it in the tree - like structure. It goes as .... the file has a president that is at the root. the president's employee id will be the  designation id of the Manager. Accordingly, manager's employee id will be the designation id  of the remaining employee's that includes Analyst , Clerk , Salesman. such is the tree. However , i am noticing a hindrance. 
In the line :

```
if (valueOfPresident == Integer.valueOf(b[3]).intValue())
```

while comparing the President employee id with the designation id of other employee's , it encounter's a NULL 
(7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,'17-NOV-81',5000,NULL,10 )
while the other employees have the integer value like this -->
(7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,'1-MAY-81',2850,NULL,30).
Because of which i am getting an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NULL"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.techlabs.compositepattern.project.CompositePattern.main(CompositePattern.java:34)
```

How do I replace the NULL value with 0?

program code is  -

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] b = line.split(",");

        if (b[3].equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) {
            TopHierarchy tophierarchy = new TopHierarchy(b);

            valueOfPresident = (Integer.valueOf(b[0]).intValue());

            tophierarchy.showDetails();
            if (b[3].contains("NULL"))
            b[3].replace("NULL", "0000");


            if (valueOfPresident == Integer.valueOf(b[3]).intValue()) {
            TopHierarchy    tophierarchy1 = new TopHierarchy(b);
                tophierarchy.add(tophierarchy1);
                tophierarchy.showDetails();
                valueOfManager = Integer.valueOf(b[0]).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this if statement:

```
if (b[3].equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) {
```

When you are inside it, there's no need to check b[3]. You know it is "NULL" so you can remove the 2 if statements.

Comment: Then how do i check and segregate the manager from other employees . I need to check if the employee id is the designation id of the managers .      Like an excerpt  from file:                                                                          7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,'1-MAY-81',2850,NULL,30  And 7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',0000,'17-NOV-81',5000,NULL,10 .                   Here the Designation id of Manager - 7839 is the employee if of president - 7839

Answer (score 0):

This does nothing:

```
b[3].replace("NULL", "0000");
```

Strings are immutable. The `replace` method returns a new string. You need:

```
b[3] = b[3].replace("NULL", "0000");
```

But you are calling this inside a block which has already checked that b[3] equals "NULL". So there is no need to put `if (b[3].contains("NULL"))` in front of that.

Comment: I need to convert and replace b[3] ==NULL to a numeric value

Comment: I know. So do what my answer says.